# How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

I would very much like to disable the sliding animation that occurs when switching desktops via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> in Lion.   This was previously accomplished in previous versions with this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES && killall Dock
```

This new animation is even more slow than in Snow Leopard - nearly 1 second to switch - a real productivity killer.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: For me, it's not so much the time, more that to be my most productive I switch desktops like a a crazy man, I find this new animation is making me feel sick... no need for the background and ALL desktop icons to move every time is there. will post back here if I find a solution.

Comment: I agree with Rob, the animation creates the same feeling as being seasick. Just a way to make it faster or even remove that small bit of easing at the end would be good.

Comment: This is probably a situation where the problem is simply still too new. Over the course of time, I expect there to be numerous articles about this sort of thing and integration into the various "preference-changing" apps like Onyx. You may just have to wait a little while.

Comment: @Rob background, icons, *and menubar*: the latter could just fade in in place, and slide up when reaching a fullscreen app space.

Comment: I added a small bounty in the hopes for someone to put in some effort of actually trying to find a method to do this, simple google fu just won't cut it.

Comment: What a great thread! Thank you Samuel for the trick to enter Mission Control switch with zero lag! Amazing. I'm also patiently waiting for a way to turn off the space-switchin animation in Lion. It is utterly annoying. I can't understand why they had to make the desktop and menu bar move as well. It was much better in 10.6 when only the active app windows moved. Now that everything moves and is animated, it makes me very dizzy as I switch spaces constantly. At least using ctrl+number keys have a quicker animation than ctrl+arrow keys. But I would prefer to use the arrow keys. The way spaces wo

Comment: We really need an app to manage all the animation speeds in Lion...

Comment: Patiently waiting for spaces fix, still can't believe there isn't a solution. Absolutely loathe that animation.

Comment: If the only app you want fullscreen and not doing this happens to be iTerm, you're in luck: in the General panel of the preferences, there's a checkbox "Use Lion-style Fullscreen windows" that defaults to checked. Uncheck it and iTerm will be able to go fullscreen behind other windows.

Comment: I hate you Apple. I love workspaces on any system, but I'm about to throw up. It's just messed up, really.

Comment: Using desktops with app windows maximized and no menu bar seems to be the best possible option. Switching using `ctrl`+`[0-9]` is awesome! [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1187552) is a great explanation for setting up multiple desktops.

Comment: The most annoying thing for me is that it doesn't register the second press. I use workspaces a lot, and have my own workspace for every common task (relics from working in a tiling WM). I sometimes do mess up the number, go to workspace 6, then the animation already shows me I'm wrong, so I press `ctrl+7`, but that last one isn't registered while the animation is still playing... Then I start typing in the wrong program

Comment: The check box should be labeled "Reduce motion sickness."

Answer (score 189):

I posted a bug on [Radar#28495374](https://bugreport.apple.com) and here is the response from Apple:

> Fixed in 10.12.  Go to Accessibility and Turn on Reduce Motion…
>
> Please let us know whether the issue is resolved for you by updating your bug report.

[image: Reduce motion in Accessibility mac os 10.12]

Comment: This is great! I get dizzy otherwise.

Comment: Maybe related, but if you use "Reduce motion" on iPhone some features are not available (like the long press on iMessage send button) so Apple may do it on macOS too

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Does this switch instantly?

Comment: @LenarHoyt Yes :) (there is a bit of fading / loading for like 100ms maybe)

Comment: WOW! After the other comments I got completely disillusioned and sad about my macbook. Why won't Apple let me use my macbook productively?... Why must I suffer headache and confused dizziness from everything moving around all the time? Why should I wait for that? This helps. Really wish you could just disable animation in this case..

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Somebody knows if I can switch this on with a command from the CLI?

Comment: I wonder if we're able to get rid of the 100ms fade as well.

Comment: @LenarHoyt no, unfortunately this does not switch instantly.

Comment: Finally, I can use desktops! :)

Comment: I've got my mac connected to an external monitor. For some reason, this works when the mac is closed, but as soon as I have the mac open, it reverts to the sliding animation.

Comment: @CosminPascu I think there shouldn't be any technical difficulties for them to do so, as zero animation has already been a feature of totalspace2. Just wondering why apple wouldn't do this one last favor for us

Comment: how to get rid of the stupid 300ms fade

Comment: That's very unfortunate.  The Mac OS feature is useless with this strongly noticeable delay.  That's a ridiculous amount of time and focus lost if I'm switching between desktops hundreds of times a day.  The app some people are recommending also hasn't posted to their blog for over a year so not interested in trying that.  https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: this no longer appears to work in ventura 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: For me it works in Sonoma 14.0.

Answer (score 112):

I dug deep into the app [using GDB](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html) but the results were disappointing. I don't think there is a way to do this currently. Here's what I learned:

First you can change the speed of switching into Mission Control (still called Expose in the prefs). To do that just enter this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock
```

And to go back to defaults run this command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration; killall Dock
```

Secondly there's a reference in the binary to `fps-spaceswitch` (frames per second spaceswitch). I messed with this for a while and also tried variations on this such as `spaceswitch-animation-duration` without luck.

Unfortunately (at least as of 10.7.1) there does not appear to be a way to change any settings related to this animation.

I filled a bug for this with Apple. The Radar number is 10073864. I would encourage you to also file the report at https://bugreport.apple.com/. Note in your description that it is a duplicate of the above bug report number to help the support staff categorize and prioritize this bug.

Comment: Instead of using an -int you can actually use a -float and set it to fractions. I set mine to 0.20, it is not nearly as jarring as setting it to 0 whereby it just flashes into place and sort of leaves an animation.

Comment: Were you able to find anything that handled the Command-M - motion blur effect in Mission Control? I just stumbled on that - it might be causing unintentional grief if some people have accidentally enabled that <ahem> _fine_ </ahem and clears throat again loudly for effect> piece of work.

Comment: I am glad you looked into this, but I am sad that the bounty got awarded when we still don't have an answer.

Comment: another work around is to use double-tap-jump-back to quickly switch back to the last space you were using. to enable: defaults write com.apple.dock double-tap-jump-back -bool TRUE;killall Dock
From: http://www.cultofmac.com/133205/use-a-secret-gesture-to-switch-to-the-previous-space-os-x-tips/#GfPSPXpjSQuLqMCH.99

Comment: @Cam thanks very much for sharing that. works great. "annoyingly" (since we can't figure out a real setting to use) it's a noticeably faster transition than all the other methods! it settles much more quickly than using ctrl-arrow.

Comment: bug #15348128 filed

Comment: ...and Apple has responded wontfix: "Engineering has determined that this is not to be fixed.

If you have questions regarding the resolution of this issue, please update your bug report with them.

We are now closing this bug report."

Comment: bug num 16079706 filed.  Just keep filing folks, they've gotta listen one day.

Comment: It seems that TotalSpace2 does this by attaching a CFPlugin to the Dock.

Comment: Filled a duplicate as 28495374, hope this will be solved, it's doable on Linux desktops...

Comment: If you want to let others know the existence and status of bug reports you send to Apple, you can post your reports to [Open Radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/) as well ([about](https://openradar.appspot.com/faq)).

Comment: is there a solution closer to 2022? this doesn't seem to work on the new M1 with macos Ventura

Answer (score 48):

I've just noticed that doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> is noticeably faster than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd> .

It's still animated but it does complete the animation in about half the time.  I'm not sure if that helps but I'll throw that out there.

Comment: you, sir, win the internet. thankyou so much. another note is that when using `ctrl` + `[number]` it skips other desktops in between the current one and the `[number]`th one.

Comment: Great, thanks. As I usually use two spaces at most, I have replaced the numbers for arrows and now it is at least faster.

Comment: unfortunately ctrl+number can't switch to fullscreen apps

Comment: Ctrl+number works for full screen apps in 10.8.5  Note that you have to enable the Ctrl-number shortcuts in the System Preferences Keyboard panel and you can only do so for 1-4.

Comment: Cmd + tab is the fastest I could find for switching full-screen apps

Comment: I just have an option to activate shortcut to "switch to Desktop 1" but not the other ones. Any idea?

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1187552) is a great explanation for setting up multiple desktops. Using desktops with app windows maximized and no menu bar seems to be the best possible option. Switching using `ctrl`+`[0-9]` is awesome!

Answer (score 45):

[TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) has an option to disable the animation for changing spaces:

[image]

<s>TotalSpaces is still in beta and a bit glitchy though. There's a small delay before changing spaces, and the whole screen seems to move a few pixels horizontally during the transition.</s> Edit: both of those have now been fixed.

Comment: This app sure is promising - I hope more people find it and help shake out the remaining bugs. It's a really nice power user tool and solves a hole in window management if you come from other WM to Mac.

Comment: This is awesome. The single row of space drove me crazy enough when lion came out that I briefly considered implementing something like this, but didn't get around to it. Here's to hoping it gets fixed in Mountain Lion but in the meantime, I'm shelling the $12 to register this app.

Comment: The delay before reacting to a keypress is a deal breaker for me, but I'll be watching this app for better performance in the future.

Comment: I tried totalspaces. It works really well, when it works. It seems to get confused when I add/remove spaces, and it won't ctrl-rightarrow properly through all the spaces/fullscreen apps.

Comment: @Sparr: (At least) in 0.11.0 you can eliminate the delay via TS's preferences by unchecking `Use transitions` in the `Transitions` tab _and_ unchecking `Show notification graphic on desktop change` on the `General` tab. @Gattster: Make sure the layout settings on the `Layout` tab match the actual number of desktops defined and that `Navigate right to additional full screen apps` is checked. For full-screen app integration with multiple desktops, use the `Advanced` tab. NOTE: _Whenever you change the number of desktops via Mission Control, you need do make corresponding changes in TotalSpaces_.

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me in Mountain Lion. Be sure to un-bind the OS-level shortcuts for desktop switching.

Comment: @mklement Upgrading from 0.10.0 to 0.11.0 eliminated most of the delay, and unchecking "Show notification graphic on desktop change" got rid of the rest. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Totalspaces wont work in el capitan without disabling security. How would you do it in el capitan?

Comment: Totalspaces only works with El Capitan when you modify system integrity protection, which is not an option for many. Sad because this is the only reason I have been using it.

Comment: This does not seem to work in my Mac OS Yosemite. Transitions are still there. And General tab in Preferences takes ages to update. It gets stuck many times.

Comment: Although it needs disabling security, it works for my case (10.11). When using alt tab to switch between apps in different desktops, the transition is immediate now because I disabled animation through TotalSpaces.

Comment: works well on 10.13 high sierra, with crsutil disabled during install. The free version is a 14d trial. Full app at 12$, not expensive, but I'm not comfortable for the time being to pay 12$ to remove a fade animation

Comment: Checking in from macOS Big Sur 11.6 in Nov 2021 - this app still works brilliantly to remove the delay when switching desktops. I had to run `csrutil disable` in Recovery Mode, and I also have "Reduce Motion" enabled if that makes a difference. Big thanks all around.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Don't upgrade to Monterey.

Comment: Doesn't work with Ventura 13+

Answer (score 13):

I noticed that it is possible to control the speed of the space-change animation when you use the Swipe gesture in OS X Lion.  You can make the spaces change as fast, if not faster, than they did in Snow Leopard by doing a quick three-finger or four-finger swipe to the left or the right.  Of course, it's definitely something to get accostomed to if you've always used <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>.

This did get me thinking.  Since it seems that changing spaces via arrow keys, number keys, and gestures all perform the same type of animation, there is likely a single system command that all three of these actions map to.  Additionally, since they all perform the animation at a different speed, there must be a parameter that controls the animation speed.  I'm not an OS X developer, so hopefully someone else with a better knowledge of the underlying functionality of OS X would be able to determine what system commands are actually running when the user performs a certain action.

Comment: The finger swipe actually is faster when you swipe faster. It goes the same speed of your hand for the most part. Obviously this is an Apple knows best kind of decision - it feels natural until you use it for a long time and get sea sick!

Comment: Frustratingly, it seems that Monterey made the threshold of what counts as this "fast" swipe a lot stricter compared to Big Sur. I have to basically throw my whole arm into it if I want it to work now.

Comment: For me it's not the speed of the swipe, it's the time-to-interactive that's the issue. Once I've animated the swipe, I'm still waiting for a second for the end 'ease' compulsory part of the animation, before the content of the desktop / windows becomes interactive, and it's infuriating!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Spaces, I have found that switching among non-fullscreen apps using the Alfred app is 'instant'. I create a key binding using shift+ctrl plus a letter for each app (e.g. e for Excel, w for Word, etc.). I have been doing this for years and the experience is truly instant.

If you put the apps in fullscreen mode, you still get the animation, so you still need to do Accessibility->Reduce Motion. In that case the app switching with Alfred is faster than using ctrl->arrow, but not as instant as it is if you avoid fullscreen.