# Mission Control Animation

Tags: macos, mission-control

I've install Lion on both MBP17 2008 and iMac27 i7 2010. On the old MBP, Mission Control animation are smooth but on the iMac, the desktop slide away with a nice animation but then all the application window appear in a snap with no animation at all.  Is there a way to turn this feature on again ?

Comment: This isn't a feature, it's a bug. Have you tried restarting?

Comment: @Nathan : yes I did.  Does not change anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion) same slowness - same desire to disable the new animation

Comment: Is the OP trying to disable the animation, or make it work again?

Comment: They're trying to make it work again.