# Mission Control slow and jerky on 2011 MacBook Pros: any fix?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, performance, mission-control

Mission Control has been *horribly* slow on my 2011 MacBook Pro 15" (2GHz quad i7, 8GB RAM, 256MB graphics, SSD) -- swiping up usually freezes the screen for 2 seconds, before showing me the Mission Control layout. I've tried switching to discrete graphics only, but the problem doesn't go away.

It seems [others](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mission%20control%20slow%20macbook%20pro&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) have been experiencing this, too, and it might be a video driver issue. Has anyone found a fix for this? One MacRumors [forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1183666) suggested disabling automatic scrollbar overlays, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: FWIW Mission control works fine on my 2007 MacBook! So you mist be having a driver problem. Are there any other circumstances where graphics freeze up?

Comment: Not really... Launchpad is decently fast. I tried this out on a 2010 MacBook Air as well, and it was _much_ faster than on my 2011 MBP. Also worth noting: this is a fresh install.

Comment: Lots of people are reporting slowness - can we close this and track [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

Comment: It's something that, while it may not be unique to your system, is certainly special about your system. I have a similarly configured 2011 MBP, and on either video card, with or without external monitor, I have seen no slowdown. I also have a 2011 MBA i5, and have likewise seen no delays either on the internal or external monitor.

Comment: @bmike - not quite the same topic, but ok to close anyway since I don't see many others facing this issue (and I'm not in a position to test it any more). Accepted the solution below, will leave it open for a couple more weeks.

Comment: Bummer that we don't get to narrow in on the issue - good that you don't face it anymore. You can always answer your own question here saying what you tried and when you gave up on things. This might be better to do if the accepted answer didn't really fix this.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem. Mission Control is laggy but everything else is working smoothly. It only started happening a few days ago, before then, everything about my Lion was working wonderfully. I have tried both a Repair Disk during boot and re-installing Lion OS as well. Neither of them worked. I have a suspicion that it might be the video card because when I tried running TechTool, it keeps closing unexpectedly when it gets to checking the video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a couple of suggestions, and neither is sure to work, but worth a try.

Safe boot - Start up in Safe mode with the Shift key held until the progress bar appears.  Select Restart (normally) at the login in window.  Safe boot mode does a Repair Disk during boot.

Re-install the OS - Your data and settings will be preserved.  There may have been a glitch in the original installation that could be fixed this way.

BTW, have you tested for this problem by logging in as a different User?

I have 3 Macs on Lion: 2007 iMac, 2009 mini, 2011 i7 MBP, none of which exhibit this problem.  This leads me to suspect that those with the problem have some 3rd party software in common, especially since it happens in such a wide range of Macs.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't have the chance to test most of these before I sold my MacBook Pro for a new Air (where I'm happily unaffected). I can say that re-installing didn't do anything, as I did a clean install of Lion. It might be something app-specific which didn't play well with the MBP's graphics card.