# Is there an Apple list of terminal based tweaks?

Tags: macos, finder, resources, tweaks

Googling for terminal tweaks shows sites [this one](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/02/top-50-terminal-commands.html) which show how to tweak OS X via the Terminal. Are there any Apple or exhaustive lists of these settings anywhere on the net?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I'm tempted to just close this since it's the equivalent of "what books can be written with a text editor" or "what programs can be thought up with Xcode". Terminal is so powerful and self-modifies the system, so the true answer is infinite.

Comment: Question seems straight forward enough - nathang pointed to one such list.  'Exhaustive'?  Well, probably only Apple could answer that but 'comprehensive' is pretty darn useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty good database full of `defaults write` commands at http://secrets.blacktree.com/

They also have a PrefPane that allows you to use System Preferences to set these hidden preferences.

(This site is no longer available)

Still available here: https://hiddensettings.1984apps.com

Comment: +1 That's a really good resource I like to just skim through!

Answer (score 2):

## [Mac Kung Fu Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356824)

It's not a free resource ($23), but I believe it should be mentioned here.

About the book:

- Many of the tips in this book exploit settings or experimental features never officially made public.
- "exploit secret settings and hidden apps"
- "tweak your system"
- "learn valuable security tricks"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there appears to be [a way to scout for these settings yourself](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html). Neat.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1]</sup> Props to [this user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9143/samuel-mikel-bowles) for linking the above article in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24173/638).

Answer (score 0):

"Tweaking" the system, Terminal based: that seems to call for mostly settings, and especially hidden settings that are envoked via a `defaults write` command.
[The most comprehensive list of `defaults write` commands seems now to be  available here.](https://www.defaults-write.com)

The specific list of operating systems to choose from looks like it only covers 10.7 Lion upto 10.11 El Capitan but the site is still actively adding new command examples.