# Prevent Xcode windows from exiting fullscreen after wake from sleep?

Tags: macos, xcode, fullscreen

Often, when I log out of my computer, I'll enable "Reopen windows when logging back in". One of the first things I'll do when I log back on, is swipe over to my fullscreen Xcode project.

The Xcode window immediately exits fullscreen mode and animates back onto my desktop. This is super annoying to me, because the animation wastes time as I try to jump back into my workflow.

Is there any way to prevent the window from shrinking upon becoming active, or at least speed up or disable the animation?

[image: This is nearly useless...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disabling the animation

This part of your question has been covered [earlier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17929). Unfortunately without success of finding a fitting answer.

> Unfortunately (at least as of 10.7.1) there does not appear to be a way to change any settings related to this animation.
>
> I filled a bug for this with Apple. The Radar number is 10073864. I
> would encourage you to also file the report at
> https://bugreport.apple.com/. Note in your description that it is a
> duplicate of the above bug report number to help the support staff
> categorize and prioritize this bug.

Comment: Only the animation part has been covered. I'm asking about the minimizing altogether. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know. I'll clarify that in an edit.