# Speed up the transition between spaces?

Tags: spaces, mission-control, fullscreen

Is it possible to speed up the transition between spaces?  I often open my applications in full screen mode but I would like the transition to be a bit faster, is there a way to speed this up (i.e. when I hit `Ctr rightarrow` it moves one space to the other quicker than the default setting).

Comment: A quick search found [this](http://www.yllier.net/SUFSA.html). However, it uses SIMBL, so I have not tried it.

Comment: I think I will hold off for a bit as SIMBL seems a bit obscure and I would prefer not to install it but exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There's a [duplicate at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/313572/os-x-lion-desktop-switching-speed), but it doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion achieves the same thing and works in newer OS X versions

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/).

The new version has the ability to remove the delay completely. Working great so far.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm really looking for something I can execute on the command line rather than an app I would need to purchase, I'd like to be able to include it in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/rudolph9/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx)

Comment: I hear ya! Your need is very similar to mine, and that would be first prize. After looking for a while, I couldn't find a command line option. :(

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a [OS X Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) setting for this, and TotalSpaces may use a hotpatching type of approach similar to SIMBL.

Comment: TotalSpaces does infact remove the transition, but breaks CMD-Tab application switching.

Comment: @Gav: I'm using 'TotalSpaces 2' 2.1.20, on Mavericks, and, maybe it's because I use a third-party Cmd+Tab replacement called '[http://manytricks.com/witch/](Witch)', but it works beautifully with Witch'd Cmd+Tab'ing. Lightning fast, no spaces switching animation, it's a dream!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, as I have not tested it out myself, but I found this terminal command [here](http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/01/17-ways-to-speed-up-mac-os-x-lion/):

> Disable the switching Spaces animation in the terminal by typing:
> `defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES && killall Dock`
>
> To enable again, type the following:
> `defaults delete com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off && killall Dock`

This completely disables the animation, and I'm not sure if that's what you want, but I imagine that if the animation is completely disabled, the switch between spaces would be instantaeneous.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That stopped working on 10.7.