# Is there anyway to speed up the animation when switching between spaces?

Tags: macos, spaces

This has been bothering me for a while now. When I got my new 16" M1 Pro MacBook Pro with a variable refresh rate display (ProMotion) I realized that the animation when switching between spaces was much longer than my 13" M1 MacBook Pro. I was wondering if there is any command buried deep inside macOS that would allow me to modify the speed of the animation. Thanks for your time!

Comment: And if anyone is wondering, spaces are virtual desktops / full screen apps

Comment: There's this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54728/speed-up-the-transition-between-spaces?rq=1 - idk if any of those solutions still work. BTW, if you use key commands Ctrl/[num] to switch Spaces the transition is literally twice as fast as using swipe or Ctrl/arrows [which means you cannot use it for fullscreen spaces, as they don't have numbers].

Answer (score 2):

You will have to switch to 60Hz refresh rate in monitor settings, after that, you won't have to wait almost a full second before you can interact with windows on the space you've switched to.
It seems to be a bug of Pro Motion variable refresh rate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: perfect. indeed, the toggle cut time in half or more before can interact.