# Speeding up switching between multiple desktops (speed up or remove transition)

Tags: macos, desktop, fullscreen, multitasking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

I am a PC user who switches between many applications and now I use many full screen apps on the Mac (aka multiple desktops) I find the "three finger swipe" animation very distracting.

Actually I've been switching so often between desktops I feel a bit nauseous. (no joke)  I'm sure this effect is exaggerated since I am using a 1680x1050 resolution on a 15 inch Retina display on a Macbook Pro.

My short-term solution is to use windowed mode for now, but I really want to use all my screen real estate.

I think that speeding up the transition animation, or making it act like a "jump cut" would  help a ton.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution here!  [OS X Daily: Speed up Mission Control Animations](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/14/speed-up-misson-control-animations-mac-os-x/)

EDIT: For the lazy ;): `defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1; killall Dock`  Change 0.1 to 0 to remove the animation entirely.

Comment: Does that affect the Dock or the transitions between desktops?  I'll try it out when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: It only affects the animation for showing and hiding the Mission Control view.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022 it seems.

Comment: @DanielPorteous no surprise, the question is over 9 years old.

Comment: Agreed, just saving someone else from having to try it to no effect as well.