# Native way to speed up/remove desktop switching animations

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mission-control, productivity

I want a native (and therefore free) way to speed up a specific animation. My research covers these questions and links on this that have gone unsolved for High Sierra and no answers there cover this natively.

- [How do I speed up the animation time for switching between desktop spaces?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314123/how-do-i-speed-up-the-animation-time-for-switching-between-desktop-spaces)
- [Speeding up switching between multiple desktops (speed up or remove transition)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/speeding-up-switching-between-multiple-desktops-speed-up-or-remove-transition/61281#61281)
- [How do I speed up the animation time for switching between desktop spaces?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314123/how-do-i-speed-up-the-animation-time-for-switching-between-desktop-spaces/314126#314126)
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/711

What used to work, `defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1` does not work, and has been confirmed to not work by myself (as well as many of the above comments and posts).

People tend to get referred [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253756/speed-up-mission-control-animations-in-macos-sierra), which only offers a paid program as a solution. I have searched and searched for a free solution, none found. Any hints, help, open source mission control replacements, anything? This thing is slow enough my workflow is getting hampered (I'll switch back and fourth a lot comparing data).

I'm really hopeful for some guru who can figure this out. How can we implement this for free?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107350/discussion-on-question-by-semimono-native-way-to-speed-up-remove-desktop-switchi).

Comment: @bmike Re-reading your comment, I guess I read the first line and the last couple of lines, missing the “since it's really just a special case of the general solution”.  So I guess I'm mostly agreeing to you; I should've just address my comment openly for anyone who comes in the future that might want to close this— which we don't want happening, since it's still an unsolved problem.  As for comment-deletion— I don't see the point; non-upvoted comments are auto-collapsed, so eh, just let the cream rise to the top.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up Mission Control animations, try:

```bsh
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1
defaults write com.apple.dock missioncontrol-animation-duration -float 0.1

killall Dock
```

And then restart.

From: https://github.com/JayNewstrom/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The main window still takes a while to "activate"

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything on 12.6.1 (Apple Silicon)

Comment: This doesn't do anything on 13.1 (Apple Silicon).

Answer (score 0):

Try going to System Preferences - Accessibility - Display, and tick Reduce motion.[image]

Comment: Well, that replaces the motion with a fade. The fades takes the same amount of time though, and keyboard shortcuts like cmd-tab are still unresponsive during the fade. That said, I think this could be a slight improvement for simply comparing data.