# How to turn off slide transition when switching between two full screen applications on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos

Application switching cause one application to slide into another. Most times this is fine but am working on a MacBook Air and the slide transition causes motion sickness at times, especially after prolonged use (4+ hours). Looking for a way to turn off these animation.

Totalspaces2 has a turn off slide transition option, so I am pretty sure it's possible. Lion, Mountain Lion had Terminal commands for animation. I tried them all, and they don't work with Mavericks. I'm looking for Mavericks terminal commands to achieve the same.

Comment: What do you call a slide transition ? Can you give an illustrated example ?

Comment: It seems there's no known solution to this

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable the animation but you might want to look at [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com), which replaces the builtin workspace manager. You can disable transitions altogether with this (as well as use different animations and layouts for spaces). It's not free ($18) but there is a 14 day free trial.

Comment: Dan is correct, for now there is no way to turn off the animations from terminal. I have tried TotalSpaces 2 (for mavericks), it does disable the animations but it does so by modding the OS itself. Wanted to point out that if you are only looking to disable the animations & not for spaces features, then TS2 trail version should suffice. Once the trial period ends the animation controls still work.

Answer (score 10):

**In MacOS Sierra:**

```
 - Go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display 
 - Check in the box "Reduce motion".
```

This new function will speed up the animation between various display motion techniques such as using the mission control, switching desktops etc.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, at least in macos 10.12.6.

Comment: Works for High Sierra as well 10.13.6
In my case I wanted the animation back and had forgotten where it got disabled..

Answer (score -3):

defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO

Comment: Although your answer may be a solution to the problem, you give no context on how the OP should execute this command, nor do you back up your solution with more explicative information and a link (or two) to authoritative sources where you discovered this solution. It may be deleted.

Comment: It's also not the right command for slide transitions, but for window zoom

Comment: This has no effect switching between full screen desktops using Ctrl+Left / Ctrl+Right arrow keys (aka "slide transitions") as mentioned previously