# Terminal app slows switching of desktops/Spaces

Tags: terminal, spaces

I noticed some time ago that when switching from one space (workspace/desktop) to another this animation is slowed if a terminal app is running on one of them. 
Funny thing I found out by experiment, the greater the terminal app window is the slower gets the switch.

Anyone can share this experience, or at best have a solution?

Bugreport is send out, and this [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion) approach is also tried. 
It first appeared with Mavericks for me and now on el capitan it's still there.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, funny, found out that changing Opacity back to 100% the switch goes just like a charm.
Leaving this for QoS in here.