# Eliminate desktop switching transition/delay

Tags: macos, catalina, desktop, spaces

When switching desktops on Mac OS, there is always a fade in/out transition. This transition is quick, but still quite noticeable and annoying when one switches few times in a minute.

Is there a way how to make the switch insantaneous? (like in windows, gnome...)
I've tried all the standard accessibility options, motion reducitons etc., to no avail.

Comment: Does this q&a help: [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

Comment: If you've gone through the Accessibility settings, we're on the same page and that's the best we can do. If you can dig deeper than answers and comments there, please do and  post an answer there. Till then, I'd vote to close. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/17929?lq=1

Comment: Non of the answers there work, unfortunately. The original question was asked in 2011 a references Lion.