# What is efficient way of switching between windows in macOS Monterey?

Tags: keyboard, monterey

Assuming I have three windows:

- browser
- terminal
- VS Code

I would like to switch between those windows efficiently, preferably with single keyboard shortcut press.

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is too slow for me, because it requires a few key presses and visual feedback.

Putting those windows in separate workspaces/desktops is too slow, because of absurdly long (~300ms) animation that [can't be turned off.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

What is efficient way of switching between windows in macOS Monterey?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and 
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar BTW, switching is literally twice as fast if you use Space numbers rather than 'left & right'.

Comment: Keyboard Maestro is the utility for maestros of the keyboard - even for would be maestros (like me). The you can define any keystroke (or keystroke combination) to activate the browser, another for terminal, etc.