# Get rid of any space-switching animation macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey, spaces

On macOS Monterey, how can I make switching spaces animation-less? I would like there to be no animation at all. As instantly as possible, just redraw the screen with the new space.

Comment: @DarkDust no, then it just slowly fades in and out instead

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255220/9058 does the trick for me. The UI has changed in Monterey, the option is still there.

Comment: Even if rewritten it asks the same thing as the original question does ("I would very much like to disable the sliding animation that occurs when switching desktops"). There are quite a few options in the answers, including an analysis on why instant switching doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @nohillside from 11 years ago. I at least didn't find an answer to my qeustion on the other page

Comment: The answers provide some options which reduce the switching time to practically zero.